# if amount == None IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently making my first ever discord bot in python and It gives me this error saying that in line 5 the "if amount == None:" is not right. I don't see the problem tho, I do not understand it.
The error is "  File "main.py", line 57
if amount == None:
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

```
 @bot.command()
 async def withdraw(ctx,amount = None):
       await open_account(ctx.author)
    
      if amount == None:
          await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount")
          return
      
    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
    
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount>bal[1]:
      await ctx.send("You don't have enough potatoes!")
        return
    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("Can only send positive potatoes! No negative!")
        return
    
    await update_bank(ctx.author,amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "bank")
    
    await ctx.send(f"You withdrew {amount} potatoes!")
```

Comment: your `if amount == None:` line should have an extra space of indentaion, in order to match the line above. Whitespace matters in Python - try using a text editor/IDE that warns you whenever your code is poorly indented.

Answer (score 1):

Your first "await" line is indented one more space than the "if amount == None".  Then later your line starting "bal" is one space less indented than that.

```
 async def withdraw(ctx,amount = None):
     await open_account(ctx.author)
     # Next line same indent as "await" above         
     if amount == None:
          await ctx.send("Please enter a valid amount")
          return
     # "bal" same indent as "if" above 
     bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
```

And so on.  Consistent indents are really essential in Python.

Comment: I just did that and now I have way more errors.
`SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`
All 6 await functions are now not correct anymore :

Comment: You have 8 await calls, so 2 of them are fine.  It's likely that some of them align with "async" and are therefore outside the function.  It's best to post a new question, with the exact code you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

The "await" is one space further in than the "if" below it.  That's causing the IndentationError.

Also, it's [generally recommended](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/comparison_to_none.html) that you use "if amount is None" rather than "if amount==None"